# Problem understanding Loss function behavior using Flux.jl. in Julia

Tags: neural-network, julia, flux.jl

So. First of all, I am new to Neural Network (NN).
As part of my PhD, I am trying to solve some problem through NN.
For this, I have created a program that creates some data set made of
a collection of input vectors (each with 63 elements) and its corresponding
output vectors (each with 6 elements).

So, my program looks like this:

```
Nₜᵣ            = 25;   # number of inputs in the data set
xtrain, ytrain = dataset_generator(Nₜᵣ); # generates In/Out vectors: xtrain/ytrain
datatrain      = zip(xtrain,ytrain);     # ensamble my data
```

Now, both `xtrain` and `ytrain` are of type `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`, meaning that
if (say)`Nₜᵣ = 2`, they look like:

```
julia> xtrain    #same for ytrain
2-element Array{Array{Float64,1},1}:
 [1.0, -0.062, -0.015, -1.0, 0.076, 0.19, -0.74, 0.057, 0.275, ....]
 [0.39, -1.0, 0.12, -0.048, 0.476, 0.05, -0.086, 0.85, 0.292, ....]
```

The first 3 elements of each vector is normalized to unity (represents x,y,z coordinates), and the following 60 numbers are also normalized to unity and corresponds to some measurable attributes.

The program continues like:

```
layer1 = Dense(length(xtrain[1]),46,tanh); # setting 6 layers
layer2 = Dense(46,36,tanh)            ;
layer3 = Dense(36,26,tanh)            ;
layer4 = Dense(26,16,tanh)            ;
layer5 = Dense(16,6,tanh)             ;
layer6 = Dense(6,length(ytrain[1]))   ;

m = Chain(layer1,layer2,layer3,layer4,layer5,layer6); # composing the layers

squaredCost(ym,y) = (1/2)*norm(y - ym).^2; 
loss(x,y)         = squaredCost(m(x),y); # define loss function

ps  = Flux.params(m);         # initializing mod.param. 
opt = ADAM(0.01, (0.9, 0.8)); #
```

and finally:

```
trainmode!(m,true)
itermax = 700;    # set max number of iterations
losses = [];     
for iter in 1:itermax
    Flux.train!(loss,ps,datatrain,opt);
    push!(losses, sum(loss.(xtrain,ytrain)));
end
```

It runs perfectly, however, it comes to my attention that as I train my model with an increasing data set(`Nₜᵣ = 10,15,25`, etc...), the loss function seams to increase. See the image below:
[image: y1: 10, y2=15, y3=25]

Where: y1: Nₜᵣ=10, y2: Nₜᵣ=15, y3: Nₜᵣ=25.
So, my main question:

1. **Why is this happening?**. I can not see an explanation for this behavior. Is this somehow expected?

**Remarks:** Note that

- All elements from the training data set (input and output) are normalized to [-1,1].
- I have not tryed changing the activ. functions
- I have not tryed changing the optimization method

2. Considerations: I need a training data set of near 10000 input vectors, and so I am expecting an even worse scenario...
3. Some personal thoughts:

- Am I arranging my training dataset correctly?. Say, If every single data vector is made of 63 numbers, is it correctly to group them in an array? and then pile them into an ´´´Array{Array{Float64,1},1}´´´?. I have no experience using NN and **flux**. How can I made a data set of 10000 I/O vectors differently? Can this be the issue?. (I am very inclined to this)
- Can this behavior be related to the chosen *act.* functions? (I am not inclined to this)
- Can this behavior be related to the *opt.* algorithm? (I am not inclined to this)
- Am I training my model wrong?. Is the iteration loop really *iterations* or are they *epochs*. I am struggling to put(differentiate) this concept of "epochs" and "iterations" into practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loss(x,y)         = squaredCost(m(x),y); # define loss function
```

Your losses aren't normalized, so adding more data can only increase this cost function. However, the cost per data doesn't seem to be increasing. To get rid of this effect, you might want to use a normalized cost function by doing something like using the mean squared cost.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense!. Now (And this brought me questions), I have seen (and copied) this part of the code (the part doing the training) from various Flux examples, and I can't see what would be the utility of doing the sum over the values of the function ```loss (x, y)``` in each iteration. Isn't this  function ```loss(x,y)``` returning a single value?. What is being added on each iteration?. Again, thanks for the response! BTW: I made a similar post in [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/problem-understanding-loss-function-behavior-using-flux-jl/44375)

Comment: I forgot to @ you. I hope there is no problem with posting this same question elsewhere. I just thought maybe this site was targeting a more specific flux audience